# Merging two columns in a DataFrame while preserving first column values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example DataFrame:

```
In [308]: df
Out[308]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  3  6
```

I want to merge A and B while keeping order, indexing and duplicates in A intact. At the same time, I only want to get values from B that are not in A so the resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
In [308]: df
Out[308]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  3  6
6  4  NaN
7  5  NaN
8  6  NaN
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated. I tried doing a concat of the two columns and a groupby but that doesn't preserve column A values since duplicates are discarded.

I want to retain what is already there but also add values from B that are not in A.

Comment: Please clarify, let's say A has values [1,1,2,4,5] and B has values [1,2,3,4,5]. Since A has 1,2,4 and 5 the B values 1,2,4 and 5 would not be added. But to retain order would the 3 be added to maintain ordinality or to maintain its place in the index. i.e. would the merged list look like this A=[1,1,2,3,4,5] B=[1,2,3,4,5,NaN] or like this A=[1,1,2,4,5,3] B=[1,2,3,4,5,NaN]?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The latter is fine i.e. A=[1,1,2,4,5,3] B=[1,2,3,4,5,NaN] is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those elements of B not in A, use the [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method with the `~` invert (not) operator:

```
In [11]: B_notin_A = df['B'][~df['B'].isin(df['A'])]

In [12]: B_notin_A
Out[12]:
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

And then you can append ([`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html)) these with A, sort (if you use [`order`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.order.html) it returns the result rather than doing the operation in place) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
In [13]: A_concat_B_notin_A = pd.concat([df['A'], B_notin_A]).order().reset_index(drop=True)

In [14]: A_concat_B_notin_A
Out[14]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    5
8    6
dtype: int64
```

and then create a new DataFrame:

```
In [15]: pd.DataFrame({'A': A_concat_B_notin_A, 'B': df['B']})
Out[15]:
   A   B
0  1   1
1  1   2
2  2   3
3  2   4
4  3   5
5  3   6
6  4 NaN
7  5 NaN
8  6 NaN
```

*FWIW I'm not sure whether this is necessarily the correct datastructure for you...*

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Much appreciated. The missing pieces for me were isin and reset_index. Pandas is a great data manipulation library.